# how to create a website / webpage that performs backend server activities

Tags: javascript, html, web

First up, I am not very sure If I am posting in the right stackexchange site. Apologize if I am posting in wrong site. Please correct me If I am wrong.

I am new to web development, Perhaps I am trying to build my first ever site for my client. We already have a old site/page which I wanna rewrite with better UI & UX.

I am trying to understand what are the technologies I need to know to build this site. The basic functionality I am looking at are

1. help user to rename, move or copy files on the server where they
   don't have access to modify files directly.
2. Interact with Database and pull some information
3. Reset password from logon page
4. Building queries for users
5. Kick off jobs

I believe HTML & CSS would be a need for the design part but I want to know which technology will help me complete the background tasks... Is it Javascript or PHP etc.. Server that I need to be running like Apache Tomcat etc

Finally If you know of a good book which could help me traverse, Please share.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You can write server side code in any programming language you like.

Comment: I use PHP for those sorts of tasks. http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-StaFQ/0/1?curriculum_id=5124ef4c78d510dd89003eb8

Comment: Welcome, and PHP would be the way to go. You're right though, this question doesn't belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: if you're new, php is probably the path of least resistance for most of this stuff. if you're a jedi, you can do this in apple basic, TCL, or c++

Comment: Frankly, you seem to be quite out of your depth. Good luck on learning web development. For this current project, I would probably let someone else take over.

Comment: @dandavis he should do himself a favor and learn node. So much better.

Comment: Don't write code that will be live on the web when you don't know what you're doing!  Learn first on personal projects/codecademy/etc, then only write code for clients when you know how it's possible to flip things up.  The internet is a wild and darwinian place, especially for someone writing their first php scripts, and you don't want it to be you vs. those hackers from russia.

Comment: @royhowieL i was thinking node, but it's actually probably not as good for someone new; php has far more examples, demo scripts, and community members for these kind of basic tasks. node is good for complicated things, or simple real-time things, but not so much for a complete data-driven site.

Comment: @kzqai, this is going to be a internal site. It won't be live on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're on the right track. If you're planning on recreating a web application, I would check out the "LAMP" stack, which covers most of the technologies needed in putting this together. I can't recommend a book, but there are tons of resources online that can get you started.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at LAMP stack. Can Java Script or Core Java do this task ? We currently have sites running using Java Script but per my understanding they just record the actions in a database and backend perl daemon job runs and completes these tasks

Comment: The way the LAMP stack breaks things down is that you have the JavaScript running on the web-page you're hosting, which can communicate with server code (which would be in PHP/Java it sounds like). The server code would then process whatever was sent from the web page, and perform the actions that you bulleted in your question.


You COULD do this all in javascript, but I don't think that that is the conventional way of doing things. Sorry I'm not able to give you a very detailed answer without actually looking at what we're comparing this to.

Comment: If you already have perl on the backend, there is a library of common perl code I've assembled to help you build perl restful services. Coupled with Javascript (AJAX), CSS and HTML, it should meet your needs. There is documentation in the wiki. https://github.com/scottoffen/common-perl

Comment: @ScottOffen Yes, We have perl on the backend. As a matter of fact, the  current page is written using Perl Common modules only which I want to rewrite in another technology with a better UI & experience for end user with more added functionalities.

Comment: @user3200612 No Problem. I got some knowledge now. Better than before, Now I atleast no what I need to know for this task.

Comment: On a web page, the UI experience is purely a function of HTML, Javascript and CSS. The backend is (or should be) irrelevant to the UI.

Comment: @ScottOffen I get your point. Thank you for the link with resources. That would really help. The reason why we wanted to switch from perl is the old version we had was written when Apache 2 or 3 was there... I don't remember the exact version but when we migrated to the latest Apache in the new environment, we really had a hard time trying to get this up and running. That is why the thought process of rewriting this in new technology came from.

Comment: @ScottOffen Is there a book that deals with this integration stuff ? Like using perl as background and still use HTML CSS for front end ? or may be a primer somewhere

Comment: @jb04, I have long considered writing one, but never thought there was sufficient demand for it. HTML/CSS/JS books usually leave the back-end up to you, while Perl-ish resources (or any other programming language specific resources, for that matter) expect that you want to do everything in code, and they dig into things like Catalyst and Mason. If I wrote one about using my libraries, it would be a short book, and you could get going fast. Maybe I should write it anyway.

Comment: @ScottOffen Please write one if you find time. It will be very helpful. Thank you :)